# SQL query to count how many values according to other fields

Tags: sql, database

I have in my cassandra database these data:

```
+----+----------+-----+-----------+---------+----------+
| ID | NAME     |        hour_date          |  value   |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+---------+----------+
|  1 | Ramesh   | 2017-04-16 05:00:00+0000  |  2000.00 |
|  2 | Ramesh   | 2017-04-16 08:00:00+0000  |  1500.00 |
|  3 | Ramesh   | 2017-04-16 11:00:00+0000  |  2000.00 |
|  4 | Komal    | 2017-04-22 05:00:00+0000  |  6500.00 |
|  5 | Komal    | 2017-04-16 09:00:00+0000  |  8500.00 |
|  6 | Komal    | 2017-04-22 17:00:00+0000  |  4500.00 |
|  7 | Komal    | 2017-04-22 05:00:00+0000  | 10000.00 |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+---------+----------+
```

By using SQL queries, I'm tring to calculate how many values each name has in a specific date. Here is the example of output I'm looking for:

Output:

```
Ramesh: 
2017-04-16 : 3 values

Komal: 
2017-04-16 : 1 value
2017-04-22 : 3 values
```

I tried doing this:

```
SELECT hour_date,name,count(value)
FROM table WHERE
                (
                SELECT hour_date from table 
                WHERE hour_date = '2017-04-16 05:00:00+0000'
                )
```

But that does not work. 
How can I query the table to give for each name and for each hour_date how many values do I have? 
I can't figure this out.

I use pyspark to make the sql queries with the cassandra connector.
Any suggestions would be very appreciated.

Comment: What database are you using? MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle...?

Comment: Also what is `hour_date` column type ?

Comment: In fact I'm using Cassandra + pyspark and I use sql to make the queries @StefanoZanini

Comment: @OtoShavadze hour_date is a timestamp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below query

```
SELECT trunc(hour_date),name,count(value)
FROM table group by trunc(hour_date), name;
```

Trunc function bypasses the timestamp and you can get the count of data of particular date with respect to the names. It you want you can also order by date and name

```
order by trunc(hour_date), name
```

Comment: something is missing in `trunc` function. it has arguments. I tried `trunc(hour_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')` but it returns nothing.

Comment: Is hour_date is a date data type? If not trunc will not work. No need to provide any arguments like data formats. describe the table and check the data type

Comment: the type of hour_date is a timestamp
Error: `Invalid number of arguments for function trunc`

Comment: Don't give any arguments. Just provide column_name

Comment: When I don't give any arguments it gives the error I mentionned earlier

Answer (score 1):

You missed group by for aggregated function count.
Try this:-

```
SELECT name,hour_date,count(value) as values
FROM table
group by name, hour_date
order by name, hour_date
```

Comment: … `ORDER BY name, hour_date;`

Comment: @Manngo Thanks. Updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use (in MYSQL):

```
SELECT name,DATE(hour_date) AS date_only, count(value) as values
FROM table
group by name, DATE(hour_date)
order by name, DATE(hour_date)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to group by the values you want to count on, which in your case are the user and the date part of your datetime

```
select  name, toDate(hour_date), count(distinct id)
from    table
group by name, toDate(hour_date)
order by name, toDate(hour_date)
```

The `toDate()` function will only keep the date part, excluding the hour, minutes and seconds.

Note also that the count argument is `distinct id`, because your version would count two rows with the same value as one.